# How can I find a file checksum (MD5 or...) from WebDAV server

Tags: java, md5, webdav, checksum, fingerprint

I need to get a file MD5 from WebDAV server.
The ETag value is not suitable for me.

Is there anyway to get a file checksum from WebDAV server using java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not part of WebDAV. That being said, you can try a HEAD request and see whether you receive a Content-MD5 header field...